# Which is closer to Old Dutch?

Tags: language, belgium, dutch, netherlands

The Dutch dialects spoken in Belgium and the Netherlands are diverse, but if a general statement can be made, which, as spoken today, is closer to the root of the language?

Comment: We could need a netherlands tag?

Comment: @Elrond, Added.

Comment: maybe http://linguistics.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @LouisRhys is right. This is a linguistics question, not a history question.

Comment: If Dutch is anything like English, *no* dialect is closer to the common root of the language.  All of them have gone through various changes to get where they are today.